# I get an error message while I try to make doxygen file show the source files according to the directories

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu-16.04, doxygen

> When I try to create a configuration file to use doxygen for the documentation, I receive this error message in the first step.

**I wanna know how we can document our files using doxygen. How can we use doxygen? I'm new at documentation. Also, I'm new at doxygen. I hope you can help me about that**

[When I try to create a configuration file, I took this error message.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5ZU7.png)

> EDIT: I almost solved the problem. I have another problem now.

**I have another problem. I created an empty folder to use doxygen properly. I work on Ubuntu. How can I make doxygen file reach to the source codes. Because my doxygen file does not see the source files. That's why, I got some error messages.**

[I receive this error message. According to the message the system cannot find the source files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i31bt.png)

Comment: please include the image inline and not as a reference, the later might disappear. Also state what you are exactly doing to create the configuration file, which version of doxygen you are using (and which OS).

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the < and >? They redirect input and output on the shell. If you want to use them in a filename, they need to be escaped with a `\\` or quoted.

Comment: @albert Do I need to install the doxygen.exe from the internet? can't we use doxygen directly in ubuntu 16.04? BTW, I do not know the version of doxygen because I did not download any doxygen file from internet.

Comment: @Lorenz I just did what internet told me. I implemented what other people did. "< ... > " struct exists in their solution page.

Comment: @albert I couldn't include the image as inline. I could not find the solution. Maybe you can help about that

Comment: To see the doxygen version use doxygen --version. To include an image use the "graph tool" (looks a bit like a mountain landscape in the edit possibility (but maybe your reputation is not high enough). On internet you don't want to use the doxygen.exe (this is windows) but the specific distribution for Linux or the source tree and compile it yourself with the aid of cmake.

Comment: Due to your edits the original question as stated in your topic is gone, please add it to the body text. Further you wrote "EDIT: I almost solved the problem. I have another problem now." how did you solve it? For a new problem create a new question and do nut change to topic of the current question. Still no inline images and still no version of doxygen mentioned.